# PC control hints for Elden Ring?

Tags: elden-ring

I have been trying Elden Ring which is obviously designed for a playstation with PC play an afterthought. So, the game keeps giving me "hints" but they are useless because they describe how to do things with a controller, not a keyboard. For example, the hint might say "To dual wield, press these buttons" or "To make a heavy attack press these buttons" where the buttons are controller buttons.

Is there a way to change the hints to display the keyboard buttons instead of the controller buttons, or some key to how to do these moves with a keyboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to the game's menu, and click to the System → Sound and Display tab, change the "Device for On-Screen Prompts" to "Keyboard and Mouse" instead of "Controller." This should solve your problem.

[image: Picture of the Setting:]

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please note that we are not a forum, we are a high-quality question and answer site, so we require answers to be well-thought out or well-supported with evidence. Would you mind adding additional info, such as an image, or add other details to your post? This will improve the quality.